# Why Event Listener "click" shows the "body" element instead of the element that I clicked on?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I went to chessboard.js https://chessboardjs.com/examples#5000 , opened Developer Tools and pasted the following code

```
document.body.addEventListener(`click`, a1);
function a1(){
   console.dir(event.target);
}
```

When I clicked on an empty chess square or on a square with a black piece, the console printed the correct result (for example, "div#e5-b9f9-a5bc-69e1-3e5a-4b82-b2bc-ffe4-966c.square-55d63.black-3c85d.square-e5").

But when I clicked on a square with a white piece on it, the console printed "body". When I right-clicked on the same square and chose "Inspect" it correctly showed an "img" element inside a "div" element in the section "Elements" of the Developer Tools (for example, <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-e2" style="width:49px;height:49px;" id="e2-f699-d489-4d29-2e6f-2a64-c1ec-e26f-fb62" data-square="e2"><img src="chessboard/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wP.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wP" style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>").

What is the reason for showing "body" instead of a correct element? What should I do to make the program show me the element I clicked on?

Comment: There may be an event handler that stops propagation for empty squares but not for occupied squares.

Comment: Pointy, yes I tend to think this too.

Comment: Andreas, could you clarify how you tried to reproduce? Empty squares don't have IMGs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't *just* use `event.target` on itself unless you really know what you're doing. Usually it goes in combination with `.closest()` which is 99% when it should be used - and that's exactly what you also need.

Also, instead of assigning event to `body`, use a nearest ancestor like `#myBoard`

Also, use "mousedown" Event - since it seems like the "click" hangs because the element never receives a *"mouseup"* to fulfill the *"click"* since the cell is manipulated programmatically

```js
function cellClick (evt){
   const elCell = evt.target.closest("[data-square]");
   if (!elCell) return; // Do nothing. No cell element.

   // Otherwise do...
   console.dir(elCell);
}

document.querySelector("#myBoard").addEventListener(`mousedown`, cellClick);
```

Since the cell elements you want to target use a [dataset Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), i.e:

```html
<div
  class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-g7"
  id="g7-06f7-5132-52ee-91f2-0b5b-ab5a-4157-7f9c"
  data-square="g7"
>...</div>
```

and since that attribute is used for all cells I used the [Attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `"[data-square]"`

Comment: Your example is totally different then OPs, it's not always possible set event listener on the element itself.

Comment: @vanowm What are you talking about exactly? It's not at all "totally different". It's exactly what OP was aiming for. And just a slight modification of OP's code.

Comment: @vanowm and yes, the above uses Event delegation - therefore it can work even if the cells are **dynamically added** at a later point in the DOM. In the case the parent `#myBoard` is also dynamically added - then you must use a well known static ancestor instead. 

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan I copy-pasted this code in the console and it didn't show anything when I clicked on a square with a chess piece. It did show correct answer when i clicked on an empty square.

Comment: @JaroslavTavgen added an explanation in the answer. It's a Data Attribute. read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: @JaroslavTavgen I tried it and it works as expected. ...Are you sure you clicked Enter after copy-pasting the **exact code I used in my answer**? When I click on any piece, empty or with figure I get in console the desired Element cell that was clicked.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Yes, I did. Correction: it DOES show the correct answer if I click on the black piece. It does not show anything if I click on the white piece.

Comment: @JaroslavTavgen you're right, I forgot to test on the White pieces. Will try to find a solution for those too

Comment: @JaroslavTavgen fixed by using `"mousedown"` or use `"pointerdown"` Event type. Just make sure to refresh the page before pasting the new code in console terminal.

Comment: The reason to use mousedown is because the elements (if the white player) are draggable. The target cell never fires/bubbles the click's mouseup because it's replaced by some other draggable instance cell.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan it works! Moreover, it works even if I change "click" to "mousedown" in my code: document.body.addEventListener(`mousedown`, a1); function a1(){ console.dir(event.target); } . How do you think, why?

Comment: @JaroslavTavgen I've already posted the reason why :) Read my comments and answer.

Comment: If you're interested in every single element on the page - then use the code you suggested, otherwise go for my solution - for all the explained reasons.